# MS Access, VBA, SQL... How to browse invoices

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query that gives me the invoice lines of the last invoice for a certain customer. It looks like that:

```
SELECT * FROM invoicelines WHERE clientID = [forms]![frmClient]![txtClientID] GROUP BY invoice# HAVING DateSold = SELECT MAX(DateSold) FROM invoicelines WHERE clientID = [forms]![frmClient]![txtClientID]
```

It returns the customer's most recent invoice.

What I want to add is a button that let me see the second most recent invoice, the third one, and so on.

I know it's not that complicated, but I have been thinking about it for surprisingly quite a while with no idea surfacing.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of selecting just the record with the Max(DateSold), could you order by DateSold descending, and then select the first, second, third, etc record as appropriate?

Comment: Actually, it is rather complicated to filter by that sort of requirement. I agree with YowE3K, have a combobox or listbox or form that simply lists the records in DESCENDING order and then select the one you want.

Comment: This solution would kind of work, but these invoice lines form together actual invoices. I'd really like to browse through past invoices and have a mental image of each previous purchase instead of the complete DESC list of every item sold. When in a list, it's quite hard to make a mental separation of each invoice.

Comment: But even if you want each invoice separately (and not each item sold) YowE3k's and June7's advice still applies.  This assumes that you have some kind of consistency with each invoicelines record so that you can sort the invoices... otherwise how are you going to identify the second, third, and so on as you stated?  Should each line of the invoicelines have the same DateSold for a particular [invoice#]?

Comment: A possible query for combox's RowSource:  `SELECT TOP 10 Invoice#, Max([DateSold]) As [InvoiceDate] FROM invoicelines WHERE clientID = [forms]![frmClient]![txtClientID] GROUP BY [Invoice#] ORDER BY Max([DateSold]) DESC`.

Comment: I must have misunderstood their advice. I can indeed sort the invoice. Every invoiceline record do have an invoice number attributed. I can therefore sort by invoice # indeed. Also, yes, every line of a given invoice has the same DateSold.
This brings me back my question: how do I make the invoices display one by one in a listbox, with a button below (say an arrow) that would allow me to browse through the previous invoices?
I will try it later today, but I think that your query will give me the list of all invoicelines for a given customer, but sorted by DateSold.

Comment: If you look carefully, my query groups on Invoice#, so it will not return "all invoicelines" for a given customer, rather it will return ONLY invoice#'s from a given customer ("one by one" as you say).  Also, the only reason I put Max([DateSold]) was to ensure an invoice# would appear only once--even if it had multiple [DateSold] values. You could also `GROUP BY [DateSold]` and `ORDER BY [DateSold] DESC` without MAX.  Also, regarding your description of a listbox with a button to browse through previous invoices -- that is precisely what a ComboBox control is, just what June7 recommended.

Answer (score 0):

For a much more visual representation of the data that you can work with create a form using these steps:

Make a query selecting the unique invoice columns (Excluding the items on the invoice) (MUST BE JUST UNIQUE FIELDS!!)

```
Select distinct [invoiceDate], [invoiceTo], [InvoiceAddress], [etc] FROM [invoicelines]
```

Now save the query and highlight it. Then create a bound form for it and save. (with the default form view of datasheet)

Now create a second form just based upon the base table. Save it.

Go back to the first form in design view.

Embed the second form you created into the first one as a sub form. (by dragging it from the object pane into your form)

Go to the properties for the subform and set the [link master fields] (main form [InvoiceNo]/ [link child fields] (subform [InvoiceNo]) for the sub form.
(make sure the forms default view is single form)

Now when you change the record on the main form you will see all the items for it. You can now freely filter the main form for specific people/locations/dates, etc.

Comment: I'll try it later today when I get a chance. Thanks for the reply